# Washing Machine Waste Discharge Issue

Tags: washing-machine

Just moved to a new house and plumbed in the washer drier. (Candy Grand Vita)

Seemed fine but it gave me error code E03 which suggests a blockage on the waste.

I took the machine out and disconnected the waste pipe and ran the same cycle with the waste pipe going into the sink and there was no problem.

So I assumed there is a problem with the disposal pipework under the sink, but when I connect to the waste without putting the washing machine back in the space the cycle also competes fine.

When I slide the machine into the space I get the same error.

I've checked to make sure I'm not restricting the pipe in any of way when putting the machine back into the space.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If an answer is helpful, please click the large check mark next to it to accept. And, please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: "*I assumed there is a problem with the disposal pipework under the sink*" What does the disposal pipework under the sink have to do with the washing machine ? I feel there is some missing information here. What is a "*washer drier*" and how is it supposed to be plumbed ?

Answer (score 1):

OK, confession time...

I changed the waste pipework to a double connection so I could connect the dishwasher and washing machine.

I forgot to take caps off new waste connection sockets!

Answer (score 0):

The preformed drain hoses sold with washers are usually quite sturdy but the preformed nature of them can lead to kinking if it is pushed into a tight space.

I know you said that you could not see any restriction on the pipe when you slid the machine into position but it is fully possible that the hose has kinked and that it looks normal from a distance. You may want to get a bright light and shine it down behind the machine to see if a kink as formed in the drain pipe. This would seem to be confirmed by all the testing that you have reported so far.

This picture of a brand new general purpose replacement drain hose shows how easily the hose can kink. Preformed hoses that are too long are one cause for this.

[image]

<sup>*[Picture Source](https://www.plumbingsupply.com/images/washing-machine-drain-hose.jpg)*</sup>

If you do not already have the type of drain hose shown below you may want to consider investing in one. They are much much less prone to kinking and their flexible nature lets them coil up behind the washer better.

[image]

<sup>*[Picture Source](https://www.lowes.com/pd/EASTMAN-10-ft-L-3-4-in-OD-Inlet-x-1-1-4-in-Outlet-PVC-Washing-Machine-Drain-Hose/50053909)*</sup>